# When refreshing or reloading, the requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: reactjs, flask, server, refresh, logout

When I refresh the page, this error cause. But when I go from one page to another this works fine.
[image: screenshot]

When I logout this doesn't work normally. After refreshing, I get the working page in my localhost but in the live server this causes the image one error.
[image: screenshot]

This is my normal login page
[image: screenshot]

Comment: May be but not sure I think the issue in your login controller if you have added any of the conditions to redirect to the login page please commented on that line and let check it.

Comment: I will check this but not working.

Comment: `<div className="modal-footer">
                            <button className="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            <Link to="/" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={logout} >
                                Logout
                            </Link>
                        </div>`  And this is my logout code. When I click a button that will apear a modal and then i click logout button this will go to login page but not working without refreshing.